# Atualizar multiplas divs do formulário após requisição post jquery/ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Eu tenho duas requisições post no formulário, uma inativa e outra ativa um cadastro, como são iguais vou exibir somente uma para exemplificar:

```
function inativarCadastro(cod) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("InativarCadastro", "Administradora")',
        data: { codigo: cod },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#administradoras").load(location.href + " #administradoras>");
            $("#mensagens-sistema").load(location.href + " #mensagens-sistema>");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("@Html.Raw(@ErrorMessages.CadastroFalhaInativar())");
        }
    });
}
```

O backend faz o update na tabela especifica setando o cadastro como inativo e preenchendo um TempData. Isso sempre está sendo realizado corretamente, não há problema quanto a isso.

```
TempData["Alerta"] = "Ativado sucesso" ou "Inativo sucesso".
```

Esse TempData trás além do texto um trecho html para personalizar a exibição desse texto:

```
<div id="msg-alerta" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button>
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i>
  A administradora de código 2 foi inativada com sucesso.
</div>
```

Na view eu tenho a seguinte div para exibir esse TempData:

```
<div id="mensagens-sistema">
    @Html.Raw(TempData["Alerta"])
</div>
```

E tenho uma tabela que exibe a lista dos cadastros e de acordo com o status dela ativo ou inativo, o que muda a cor da linha.

```
<b><table id="administradoras" /></b>
```

Sempre a tabela é atualizada sem problemas em todas as vezes, porém, a div que exibe o tempdata, nem sempre é atualizada, conforme você vai clicando  hora atualiza e exibe corretamente, hora não, em alguns momentos em vez de atualizar, ele faz é sumir com a div do formulário.

Obs:
Não é exibido nenhum erro de código ou no depurador do navegador.
Se colocar qualquer uma das duas divs para ser atualizada sozinha, funciona perfeitamente, porém, se tento atualizar as duas conforme no exemplo que adicionei fica dando essa instabilidade.

Comment: sinceramente nao estou a perceber o teu codigo. Mas porque nao devolves a mensagem directamente via json, ao inves de alojar no tempdata?

Comment: e penso que o motivo de nao veres nada, é porque ao preencheres o tempadata numa chamada ajax, nao vai fazer ao update ao que foi renderizado antes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se carrega uma página através da requisição ajax e se quer substituir diferentes fragmentos dessa mesma página, não é possível realizar a tarefa com a função load(), para esse tipo de tarefa se usa a função get() para capturar a resposta e atualizar os fragmentos:

Em vez de utilizar a função load():

```
$("#mensagens-sistema").load(location.href + " #mensagens-sistema>");
```

Use get():

```
$.get(location.href).done(function (data) {
    var novoDom = $(data);
    $('#administradoras').replaceWith($('#administradoras', novoDom));
    $('#mensagens-sistema').replaceWith($('#mensagens-sistema', novoDom));
});
```

Funcionou 100%.

Pelo que entendi do problema que estava tendo com a função load() em sequência, parece que ela acaba atualizando a página na primeira chamada e ao fazer a segunda chamada ele vai e atualiza novamente desfazendo a primeira mudança.